# Homebrew won't run, error "bad interpreter"

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, homebrew

**Preconditions:** I removed all Ruby versions from my Mac-PC. I also removed `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework` folder.

After that `brew` stop working (because it need Ruby). So I decided to install Ruby back. But Due the fact that `brew` and `RVM` depends on Ruby I had to compile Ruby 2.1.2 from sources.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**What I've got now:**

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

**Problem:** Seems `brew` totally broken down

```
brew doctor
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 23: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

**Question:** How to fix `brew`?

Comment: "I also removed /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework folder.". Really. Bad. Idea. You just broke your system Ruby, used by Apple, and expected by other software on a Mac OS machine.

Comment: "/usr/local/bin/ruby" is not where Ruby should be installed, so nothing that expects Ruby in /usr/bin/ruby is going to look for it there, including Brew. Rather than continuing thrashing around, you might consider reinstalling your system. As a first step, see if Xcode can reinstall ONLY Ruby, but don't hold your breath. I'd recommend searching on [apple.se] or [su].

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for answer! My osx isn't just a laptop where I used to watch movies. To reinstall the whole projects and stuff I need about few days, so reinstall system isn't an idea at all

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of hardware you're using. You messed with stuff you shouldn't, and fixing that isn't trivial. Reinstalling the system could be your ONLY fix if XCode can't reinject Ruby. While you might not like it, the reality is you did something that wasn't wise, and we're trying to help you fix it.

Comment: **Preconditions: I removed all Ruby versions from my Mac-PC. I also removed /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework folder**  What possessed you to do that?? Why not just just change its name by putting an "_" at the beginning? Or move it somewhere else? If you've got Time Machine set up, then do some time traveling.

Comment: @7stud when I open Time Machine, it says: `You haven’t selected a location for Time Machine backups`